# Construct operator with norm = 1/2

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I want to solve task where I should find distance to the set of non-invertible operators.

In order to solve it I need to construct an operator B with norm = 1/2 in such way that A+B is non-invertible. Where $ A: (Ax)(t) = x(t) - \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}x(s)ds$ is defined in $L^2[0,1]$

Can anyone help? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! As this site is meant to be a useful repository rather than a Do My Homework forum, it's common courtesy to show what you've already tried, and really narrow down what you're struggling with. Most people here are glad to help once you've adequately motivated the problem. [Quick Guide](http://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34067/21813) to attracting answers and preventing your question from being deleted. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $B=-\frac 1 2 I$. Then  $A+B$ is not invetible becasue $(A+B)x(s)=0$ when $x(t)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

The operator is of the form $A=I-{1\over 2}P$, where $P$ is a nontrivial projection. In OP case $P$ is the projection onto constant functions. We have $$A=(I-P)+{\textstyle{1\over 2}}P$$ There are many possibilities for $B.$
Let $$B_a=-{\textstyle{1\over 2}}P-a(I-P),\qquad 0\le a\le {\textstyle{1\over 2}}$$
Then
$$\|B_a\|={\textstyle{1\over 2}},\qquad A+B_a= (1-a)(I-P)$$

The operator $A+B_a$  is not invertible and vanishes on the range of $P,$ i.e. on constant functions.

It can be shown that there are no other possibilities for $B.$